# How to sort DateTime by Hour:Minutes (Ignoring date)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I need to order `@events` by hour, without date.
I have the code:

```
<% @events.sort_by(&:start_time).each do |event| %>
    <%= event.start_time.strftime('%H:%M') %>
<% end %>
```

The result is:

```
02:00 # => 2015-11-27 02:00:00 +0200
03:05 # => 2015-11-27 03:05:00 +0200
04:00 # => 2015-11-27 04:00:00 +0200
`03:45 # => 2015-12-04 03:45:00 +0200`
```

The needed result is:

```
02:00 # => 2015-11-27 02:00:00 +0200
03:05 # => 2015-11-27 03:05:00 +0200
'03:45 # => 2015-12-04 03:45:00 +0200'
04:00 # => 2015-11-27 04:00:00 +0200
```

The problem is that the last row has a much newer date.
How can I sort the `@events` to get the result above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@events.sort_by(&:start_time)` should be..

```
@events.sort_by{|ev| ev.start_time.strftime('%H:%M')}
```

or

```
@events.sort_by{|ev| [ev.start_time.hour, ev.start_time.minute]}
```

I have tried them using the same input you provided and they worked perfectly. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the code as below:

```
@events.sort_by{|e| e.start_time.strftime('%H:%M')}
```